# Range over slice and pointer

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I have the following range over a slice of a specific struct:

```
var t1, t2 *time.Time
for _, d := range entries {
    if d.EntryType == print {
        t1 = &d.LogTime
    }
    if d.EntryType == saw {
        t2 = &d.LogTime
    }
}
```

In my example I have two objects in my struct and I know that they are different. But when I Println both Time pointers with String or when I make some calculations, I can see that both have the same value of the second one.

When I change the assignment to

```
tmp := d.LogTime
t1 = &tmp
```

i can make my calculations, because both pointers are pointing to different objects.

Comment: Can you show more of the code? It doesn't really make sense as each time around the loop t1 or t2 will be overwritten from previous loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application is taking the address of the variable `d`, not the address of a slice element. The variable `d` is scoped outside the loop and has the same address on each iteration of the loop.

The code

```
tmp := d.LogTime
t1 = &tmp
```

works because `tmp` is scoped inside the loop.

Perhaps you intended to take the address of the slice element. If so, use this code:

```
for i:= range entries {
    if d.EntryType == print {
        t1 = &entries[i].LogTime
    }
    if d.EntryType == saw {
        t2 = &entries[i].LogTime
    }
}
```

There may be a reason to use `*time.Time` values here, but typically applications work with `time.Time`.  This code may do what you need:

```
var t1, t2 time.Time
for _, d := range entries {
    if d.EntryType == print {
        t1 = d.LogTime
    }
    if d.EntryType == saw {
        t2 = d.LogTime
    }
}
```

Comment: Ummm ... what are you saying>